# British Kids TV show involving collecting pieces of a MacGuffin over a series

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this television show in around the 1989-1994 period in the UK. It would have been on Children's BBC or Children's ITV programming. I think there were several seasons/series. In each season, the antagonist would somehow break up a magical artefact (something like a chalice) into several pieces (perhaps 6-10 pieces) and scatter them to different locations. In each episode of the season, the protagonists would find one piece, and in the finale bring them back together. I don't think the actual artefact they were seeking was actually that important in the end, ie it was a MacGuffin.

There were definitely some magical elements but the main protagonists were "normal" children I believe. My memory of this is very fuzzy so certain elements may be incorrect.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like T-Bag, which ran on CITV from 1985 to 1992. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-Bag):

> Each series (apart from the last) followed a similar format, T-Bag (after reuniting with T-Shirt, either through grovelling or putting him under her power) would attempt to increase her power and there would only be one thing that could stop her. The components that made the item work would be scattered across time and space, and the girl of the series was required to travel and collect them all before T-Bag could get her hands on any of them.

Comment: Now there's a name that didn't age well...

Answer (score 13):

Although the question has been answered and accepted, it might be of interest to people finding this question through a search that the description is similar to the *[Through The Dragon's Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Dragon%27s_Eye)*, a 10 chapter long BBC educational series, which premiered in 1989 and was shown regularly on TV as well as being used as an educational resource.

The series follows  a group of schoolchildren who enter a fantasy world and are guided by a dragon named Gorwen as they find the missing pieces of the 'Veetacore', which look like glowing golden fragments, gathering them over the course of the series in order to ultimately repair a machine.